# Powershell Script for adding Active Directory users to groups

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, active-directory

Hey guys in a bit of a pickle here with this script.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$list = Import-csv "\\ca23fs1\IT\Scripts\Active Directory\New-Hire\Account Setup\Users-Groups.csv"
    ForEach ($item in $list) {
            $users = $item.Username
            $groups = $item.Group
        Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $users -MemberOf $groups -Whatif |
        Set-ADUser $users -HomeDirectory "Path" -Homedrive H -WhatIf
        }
```

---

When running `$list`, i get the output from the CSV file, but when running `$users` or `$groups` nothing shows up so i think I'm missing something in my syntax that should be grabbing the data from the "Username" and "Group" headers in the CSV and passing it to the loop.

Here is what my CSV looks like:

[image: CSV]

And here is the error:

[image: Error]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*edit

Thought it might be the CSV so I made one from a txt file like so:

```
Username,Group
User1,group1
,group2
,group3
,group4
,group5
```

Still didnt work :(

I think it might be because I am using blank columns. Going to try separate CSV files for users and groups.

Comment: Are you really importing a CSV file? The image shows two columns in Excel..

Comment: I am not sure if I made the CSV file correctly. Made it in excel and saved as CSV format. Should be right no? Editing main post with CSV info.

Answer (score 0):

$item is not populated. You state that $users = $item.username but $item is null at that point.

Try this:

```
$list = Import-csv "PATH"

ForEach ($item in $list) {
$users = $item.Username
$groups = $item.Group


Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $users -MemberOf $groups -Whatif |
Set-ADUser $users -HomeDirectory "Path" -Homedrive H -WhatIf
}
```

This basically says: For each item in list, use the .username and .group syntax to populate the users and groups variable. Then, run the Add and Set commands. 
Remember, this is a loop that runs once for each $item in the $list.

Test code:

```
$list = Import-csv "PATH"

ForEach ($item in $list) {
$user = $item.Username
$group = $item.Group
Write-Host "$user is in $group"
}
```

Comment: I've tried switching around the variables but can't seem to get the right combo.

Comment: Thank you very much, after making that change I am getting an error: "Cannot find object with identity '' under 'dc=dn,dc=com'". It looks like the $list variable is not passing the Username/Group information because I return nothing when running $users and $groups but $list gets the info from the CSV

Comment: @Zeplike, I expect you are importing the csv incorrectly. Your code, when I run it, returns what you want it to. Here is the code that I ran as a test, see if it works for you.

Comment: I hear you completely. I've copied your code exactly and it does write-host with the output, as soon as I add Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $group in the mix it throws this error: "Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot find an object with identity: ''". Editing the original post with the exact code. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from not specifying a valid `Identity` value for the user or possibly even not specifying a valid `MemberOf` value.

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps), both parameters want either a `DistinguishedName`, an `ObjectGUID`, a `SID`, or a `SamAccountName` to work with.
By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output, unless you use the `-PassThru` parameter.

In your case, I think you are trying to use the `SamAccountName` and that should work just fine.
However, the problem here seems to be the CSV file you are using.

When saving an Excel as CSV file, one might expect te result would be a *comma* separated values file as the name CSV implies.
Unfortunately, Excel uses the current systems locale to determine the delimiter to be used. On my Dutch machine for instance, it will use a semi-colon `;` as delimiter.

If you do not check that, the `Import-Csv` cmdlet without the `-Delimiter` parameter will assume a *comma*.
So, after exporting from Excel, open the csv file with Notepad or any other text editor to see what is created and which delimiter character is actually used. 
You may also overcome that problem by using the `-UseCulture` switch on the `Import-Csv` cmdlet, but this will only make sense if you are exporting from Excel and importing in PowerShell on the same machine (or at least one that uses the same culture)

What you SHOULD have is a valid CSV file, something like this:

```
"UserName","Group"
"user1","group1"
"user2","group1"
"user3","group1"
```

Since your manually created CSV has empty values for the `UserName` column, it is not surprising you are getting the error.

Then, with a few more changes to your code, this should work:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# assuming the CSV uses commas as delimiter character. Otherwise, specify -Delimiter parameter
$list = Import-csv "\\ca23fs1\IT\Scripts\Active Directory\New-Hire\Account Setup\Users-Groups.csv"
foreach ($item in $list) {
    # if you are not sure the CSV actually contains valid data to work with, check it here first:
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item.UserName) -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item.Group)) {
        Write-Warning "Empty entry found in the CSV file"
    }
    else {
        Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $item.UserName -MemberOf $item.Group -Whatif
        # The DriveLetter must be a single, uppercase letter and the colon is required.
        Set-ADUser -Identity $item.UserName -HomeDirectory "Path" -HomeDrive 'H:' -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Hope that helps